# how to resize disk space in ubuntu on VM?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, diskspace

I am new to `ubuntu` when I install it on `virtualbox` I assign it 8gb normal size of disk space, but now it shows me popup for low disk space. I don't know how can I increase disk space to get rid of this warning.

I tried using following command: `VBoxManage modifyhd YOUR_HARD_DISK.vdi --resize SIZE_IN_MB` but received an error

```
'VBoxManage' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Matas Vaitkevicius can i increase it without reinstalling it?

Comment: I think you need to go to virtual box settings for that instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your host OS is Windows. Since VBox program directory is not in PATH variable by default, you need to specify a full path manually. Or change current dir to VBox program dir.
Try to run

```
cd C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
```

first to change current directory in cmd, and then run your command.